# Phi and Pi relation

Tags: trigonometry, pi

$$ \sin( \pi /2) = 1 $$ 
$$ \sin(\phi ) = 0.99889 \approx 1 $$
Can we say that: 
$$ \pi/2 \approx \phi $$
and hence,
$$ \pi \approx 2 \phi $$

Comment: Well, numerically, they are decently close...

Comment: Sine is a $2\pi$-periodic function, hence there are other possibilities of $\phi$. E.g $\phi \approx \pi/2 + 2n\pi$ with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Eff true, though that doesn't seem to be what the OP is getting at. Restricting the interval to $[0,\pi]$ is natural here. Really this is all coincidence of course, simply because $\pi/2$ and $\phi$ have an absolute difference of about $0.047$

Answer (score 2):

> Can we say that: 
>   $$ \pi/2 \approx \phi $$
>   and hence,
>   $$ \pi \approx 2 \phi $$

Yes, **but not because $\sin \phi \approx \sin (\pi/2)$**.  Since there is no other context here (and therefore no way for me to know which methods are allowed or not), I will say that we can simply see $\pi/2 \approx \phi$ from a calculator.

But in general, $\sin x \approx \sin y$ does not mean that $x \approx y$.  This is because sine is periodic.  For example, in radians, $\sin 0 \approx \sin(13815119.1366)$, but certainly $0$ is not approximately equal to $13815119.1366.$

Comment: If we restrict ourselves to the interval $[0,\pi]$ then we have $\sin x \approx \sin y \implies x \approx y$, and this domain restriction is pretty natural.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: No we don't -- for example, $\sin 2 \approx \sin 1.141593$ but $2 \not\approx 1.141593$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm oh yeah, bijection is required. Alright, then $[0,\pi/2]$

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that $\sin$ is a periodic function, 
the value of $\sin(x)$ changes very slowly when $x$ is near $\frac\pi2.$
Hence the fact that $\sin(x) \approx 1$ and $0 < x < \pi$ gives us
some idea that $x$ is close to $\frac\pi2,$ but it does not give us a very good indication of *how* close.

In this case, $\sin(\phi)$ differs from $\sin\left(\frac\pi2\right)$
by less than $0.12\%,$ but
$\phi - \frac\pi2 \approx 0.0472,$ so $\phi$ is more than $3\%$ greater than 
$\frac\pi2.$
That's an approximation of some sort, but not nearly as good an approximation as the approximation $0.99889 \approx 1 .$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the derivative of $\sin x$ is $0$ at $\pi/2$, and so a small change in $x$ won't affect the result a ton. Since $\pi/2$ and $\phi$ have an absolute difference of $0.047...$, this can be considered a small change in $x$, and will yield a small change in the output.

---

Note that the derivative being zero at $\pi/2$
 is important, because it means $\sin(x) $ is roughly flat in small neighborhood around $\pi/2$. If we chose a function with non-zero derivative we could get much more different result; for example, $e^{\pi/2} - e^\phi = - 0.23...$